# showing that $Te_n \to 0$ in a Hilbert space.

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

If $H$ is a Hilbert space, $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal sequence in $H$, and $T \in K(H)$, then $Te_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

$K(H)$ is the space of compact operators.

By a contradiction, assume that $T(e_n)$ has a subsequence that converges to $v\neq 0$.
for simplicity, let $Te_n$ be that subsequent.
Define:
$v_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=n}^{2n} e_k$
Now $||v_n||^2=(v_n;v_n)=\frac{n+1}{n^2}$ so $v_n \to 0$ an n approaches $\infty$
By linearity of $T$ we get that:
$Tv_n\to T(0)=0$.
On the other hand,
$||Tv_n||=||T(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=n}^{2n} e_k)||=||\frac{1}{n}  \sum_{k=n}^{2n} T(e_k)|| \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=n}^{2n} ||T(e_k)||$.

And the last expression approaches $||v||$ as $n,k \to \infty$. Thus $Tv_n\to v$, getting a contradiction!

Here I used a similar approach I saw here in the site, with my own calculations..

I will be grateful if you can correct/evaluate my way.

Comment: From $\|T v_n\|\le\|v\|$ asymptotically, you cannot conclude that $T v_n$ doesn't converge to $0$. You need a bound in the other direction!

Comment: Hi @Maximilian Janisch then the way is not correct? Or how it can be fixed, can you suggest another solution to the problem.

Comment: I would fix it this way: $$\|v-Tv_n\|=\left\|v-\frac1n\sum_{k=n}^{2n}T(e_k)\right\|=\frac1n\left\|-v+\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\big[v-T(e_k)\big]\right\|\le\frac1n\left(\|v\|+(n+1)\max_{k\in\{n,n+1,\dots,2n\}} (v-T(e_k))\right)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0,$$ so $Tv_n\to v$. An easier argumentation is this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815002/

Comment: Thanks @Maximilian Janisch so everything will be find once I do the correct inequality as you mentioned.

Comment: Yup and you’re welcome 

Comment: Hi! @Maximilian Janisch  i returened to this question, and did not figure out why the last expression approaches 0 as $n\to \infty$, in addition in my calculation above is that right $||v_n||^2=1/n^2$? Thanks

Comment: You mean the expression in my comment? First, $\frac{\lVert v\rVert}n$ goes to $0$. Second, $\frac{n+1}n \lVert v -T(e_k)\rVert\le 2 \lVert v-T(e_k)\rVert$, but $T(e_k)\to v$ by assumption so this also goes to $0$.

Comment: Yes, thanks! And in my post I calculated $||v_n||^2$ twice but had different answers, shouldn't it be $\frac{n+1}{n^2}$ according to how I defined $v_n$?

Comment: As mentioned in my first comment, your argument unfortunately doesn't work the way it is currently formulated. But to answer your question: We have indeed, since the $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are orthonormal, $$\lVert v_n\rVert^2 =\langle v_n, v_n\rangle =\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=n}^{2n} \langle e_k, e_k\rangle=\frac{(2n-n+1)}{n^2}=\frac{n+1}{n^2}$$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left|\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} T(e_k) -T(e_{2n})\right|\right|\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\left|\left| T(e_k) -T(e_{2n})\right|\right|$$
But for sufficiently large $n$
$$\left|\left| T(e_k) -T(e_{2n})\right|\right|<\varepsilon$$
for all $k\geq n.$
Hence $$||Tv_n -v ||\leq \left|\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} T(e_k) -T(e_{2n})\right|\right| +||T(e_{2n} ) -v||<2\varepsilon$$
for sufficiently large $n.$
So $Tv_n \to v$ which is impossible since $T$ is continuous.