# T is not compact and orthonormal sequence

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show that if  $\,T$ is not compact then there exists an orthonormal sequence $x_{n}$ and  $R>0$ such that $ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}\,\,\,\,\|T(x_{n})\|\geq R$. It is obvious by the definition of compact operator that we can find a sequence satisfying the above condition but how can we find an orthonormal one? Thank you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73069/show-u-n-orthonormal-a-compact-implies-au-n-to-0?rq=1

Comment: this question is not answered