# Image of orthonormal basis under compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let T be a compact operator on a Hilbert space H. Then we need to prove that the sequence formed on taking the image of an orthonormal basis goes to 0.
I read a proof which used the fact that every compact operator can be written as the limit of a sequence of finite rank operators, which I think is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73069/show-u-n-orthonormal-a-compact-implies-au-n-to-0?rq=1).
The fact that you're taking a basis does not change anything respect to the answer linked.