# Am I misunderstanding or is this characterisation of compact operators on a Hilbert space false?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

For H Hilbert and $u_n\in H$, $A\in B(H)$. The theorem is “ [Show $\{u_n\}$ orthonormal, A compact implies $\|Au_n\| \to 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73069/show-u-n-orthonormal-a-compact-implies-au-n-to-0) “. I might be losing my mind but if we take $e_i$ to be orthonormal basis and define $Ae_i=e_1$ then $A(B(0,1))=\{\lambda e_1, 0\le\lambda\le 1\}$ is compact so $A$ is compact but $||Ae_i||=1$

Comment: Consider $v_i = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n e_i$. Then, $\|v_i\| = \frac 12$, but $Tv_i = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2} e_1$, whose norm heads towards $\infty$ as $i \to \infty$. So the statement regarding $A(B(0,1))$ is false : it actually equals $\{\lambda e_i : \lambda \geq 0\}$ so that $A$ isn't bounded.

Answer (score 1):

There is no bounded operator $A$ with $Ae_i=e_1$ for all $i$. (*)

Suppose $\|Ae_n\| $ does not tend to $0$. Then there is a subsequence $(e_{n_k})$ and $r >0$ such that $\|Ae_{n_k}\| >r$ for all $k$. Now $(e_{n_k})$ is bounded. Compactness of $A$ implies there is a further subsequence $e_{{n_k}_j}$ such that $Ae_{{n_k}_j}$ converges in the norm to some $y$. But $e_{{n_k}_j} \to 0$ weakly   and this implies $Ae_{{n_k}_j} \to 0$ weakly. Hence, $y=0$ and we have reached a contradiction.

(*) : $\|A (\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac 1  k e_k)\|=\| (\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac 1  k e_1)\| \to \infty$ whereas  $\|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac 1  k e_k\|$ is bounded.